Convergence of a differential equation as $t \to \infty$.
I am very new to non-linear dynamics and the first chapter of Stephan Strogatz's book introduces idea of fixed points.
The equation is $$x' = x^2 -1.$$
This has two fixed points: $x = +1$ and $x=-1$. $x=-1$ is stable and $x=+1$ is unstable which can be concluded by simply looking at curve of $x^2-1$ ( for clarity).
I wanted to try out solving the equation and see the the value of $x$ at $t \to \infty$ at different initial conditions. As evident from the stability of the fixed points, an initial condition of $x=2$ at $t=0$ should blow the value of $x$ to $+\infty$ since $x=1$ is an unstable point.
I solved the differential equation and got this result:
$$\frac{dx}{(x-1)(x+1)} = dt$$
$$\int\left(\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)\mathrm dx = \int2\, \mathrm dt.$$
Few steps later, after using the initial condition $x(t=0) = 2$, the final equationis,
$$x = \frac{e^{2t} + 3}{3 - e^{2t}}.$$
Here, as $t\to\infty$, $x$ tends to $-1$ but should tend to $\infty$ since the initial value is at right of unstable point (in the figure). I don't understand where my reasoning has gone wrong.
Thanks for help.

By the way your solution looks, it seems you did not solve the equation correctly. Did you double check your calculation?

Hint: What happens at $t = \frac{1}{2}\ln 3$? What does the solution look like before that?

This solution does not exist for $x = \frac{1}{2}\ln 3$, so analyzing the limit as $x\to\infty$ does not tell you anything meaningful about the solution behavior when considering the IVP starting at $x=0$. Notice that $\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{2}\ln 3}~f(x)=\infty$, which matches with the instability of the critical point. In fact, any solution of an ODE that ceases to exist in finite time must blow up in a similar manner. This means that no such solution can converge to a stable critical point.

So the fact that solution blows up as we move closer from 0 to ln(3)/2 proves that x=1 is an unstable fixed point? And we don't need any analysis of what happens after ln(3)/2?

The solution to the IVP cannot stop existing at a point then continue existing after that point. Everything after the point of nonexistence is no longer a solution of the IVP. Another way of thinking about stability is “Does the solution go here as we approach the end of its maximal interval of existence?” For most solutions, this is $(0,\infty)$, but here that interval is finite and any solution with a finite interval of existence must blow up
